# Exception Handling - is this good practice?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am wondering if what i am going to do is good or bad thing. I have that class:

```
public class Element : IElement
{
    public float? Max { get; private set; }

    public float? Min { get; private set; }

    public float? Average { get; private set; }

    public bool HasValue { get; private set; }


    public void SetRange(float? min, float? max)
    {
        if (min >= max)
        {
           throw new WrongElementValueException("Min must be greater than max!");
        }
        else if (min < 0f || max < 0f)
        {
           throw new WrongElementValueException("Min/max must be greater than 0!");
        }
        else if (min > 100f || max > 100f)
        {
           throw new WrongElementValueException("Min/max must be lesser than 0!");
        }
        else
        {
            Min = min;
            Max = max;
            Average = (min + max)/2f;
            HasValue = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The user will set the values using SetRange() method. But he has some constraints like Min must be bigger than Max, and neither of them should be bigger than 100 or lesser than 0.

Should I use those exceptions in this place? Or is there any better method to handle wrong user input?
I hope my question isn't to general.

Comment: This seems reasonable to me.  Though I'm not sure the exception type is any more appropriate than a standard `ArgumentException`, but that's a minor point.  Either way, if the input is invalid and the object can't proceed otherwise then throwing an exception is an appropriate response.

Comment: @David Agreed that an ArgumentException is more appropriate as it's the expected exception in the case of bad arguments.

Comment: "The user will set the values" user of the application or user (ie. developer) of code that will call this method?

Comment: yes, this approach seems correct. You can also try using code contacts to simplify this. Here is a reference http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103779/Introducing-Code-Contracts

Comment: Looks good. Just for practice you can remove the last else..

Comment: There a re a lot of commenters saying "looks good" and not commenting on the elephant in the room: the fact that everything is a nullable. Why have you done that?

Comment: None of the `else`s are required; the exceptions will always end the method if their conditions are met. Their inclusion is a stylistic choice but I'd personally choose between including all or none, rather than just omitting one.

Comment: @David Arno I did that because not all values simply need to be set. Is is possible, that there will be no data about max or min - then it is null :) Anything thank you all for all those answers - espacially@Jon Hanna. I would give upvotes for more answers, but unfortunatelly I don't have enough reputation yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else if (min < 0f || max < 0f)
  throw new WrongElementValueException("Min/max must be greater than 0!");
else if (min > 100f || max > 100f)
  throw new WrongElementValueException("Min/max must be lesser than 0!");
```

I'd note that there is already `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` that's defined for precisely this sort of case.

```
if (min >= max)
  throw new WrongElementValueException("Min must be greater than max!");
```

This should definitely be an `ArgumentException`, but if `WrongElementValueException` inherits from `ArgumentException`, then that's fine.

Your general approach is sound. I'd consider going further:

```
HasValue = true;
```

Why allow for the class to ever not have a value. Consider if you add:

```
public Element(float min, float max)
{
  SetRange(min, max);
}
```

Now you can never have an instance without its values set, and can get rid of `HasValue` entirely.

Note though that I changed this from `float?` to `float`. You might well be advised to do that throughout the class. Otherwise if you have a need for cases where `Min` and `Max` are null, (and therefore don't want to get rid of `HasValue`) you need to catch that case in `SetRange`:

```
public void SetRange(float? min, float? max)
{
    if (min < 0f || max < 0f || min > 100f || max > 100f)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    if (min >= max)
      throw new WrongElementValueException("Min must be greater than max!");
    Min = min;
    Max = max;
    if(min.HasValue && max.HasValue)
    {
        Average = (min + max)/2f;
        HasValue = true;
    }
    else
    {
      Average = null;
      HasValue = false;
    }
}
```

(I'd also generally favour `double` and `double?` over `float` and `float?` unless you've a strong reason otherwise).

Incidentally, we generally use "exception handling" to talk about how code that's using this code deals with the fact that your code threw an exception, with just what the best thing to do is depending on the context of that code rather than this code.

Comment: Thank you @Jon Hanns :) I think you exhausted a topic completely. I will follow your suggestion about using double instead of floats. I need to keep them nullable, because there is accepted possibility, that there will simply be no data about min and max. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 9):

This is an appropriate practice, yes.

Though I imagine consuming code would be expecting an `ArgumentException` rather than this exception type, but that may be a relatively minor point.

When the input is invalid, and the object has no way of meaningfully continuing otherwise, then throwing an exception is an appropriate and expected response.  It's up to consuming code to use the object properly, handle errors, report back to the user, etc.

The alternative is for this object to "try to figure out what to do" which often leads to some pretty bad coding practices.  For example...

- Suppose you instead want to return an error message instead of throwing an exception.  What if consuming code doesn't check for that error message?  The object would be left in an unknown and invalid state and could quietly introduce bugs.  Whereas if consuming code didn't check for the exception then the program would clearly and obviously fail and would need to be appropriately corrected.  Clear and obvious failures are *a lot* easier to support than subtle and unnoticed ones.
- Suppose you want to "show a message to the user" instead.  That would requiring tightly coupling this object to a presentation layer, which defeats object oriented principles and makes the code very rigid and difficult to maintain.

This object does one thing, and only that one thing.  If it's invoked in such a way that it can't do that one thing, an exception is an expected and appropriate failure condition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Indeed I am going to show a message to the user, that he set wrong values, so he could improve them :)

Comment: @bartosz.baczek: Which I highly recommend doing :)  Just remember where the responsibility for such things resides (which you appear to be doing rather well so far).  The business logic classes just perform business logic and throw exceptions when failures occur, the presentation layer drives user input and directs the user to provide corrections in the event of failures.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

An excption is usefull whenever a valid program-flow is not possible (e.g. connection to database lost). Proofing user-input and throwing exception if values are not valid is absolutely ok thus, whereas you may also use the allready suggested `ArgumentException`.

Answer (score -3):

It's good practice to handle exception in program if you are throwing and catching it correctly. But here it's trivial matter ,no need to throw and object where as you can restrict it by simple console print.

Both will work same in this scenario.

Throwing an exception would much useful when there are many inner function calls and you don't know which one will cause exception at that time.

and By the way  don't you think these is wrong one.

**if (min >= max)
    throw new WrongElementValueException("Min must be greater than max!");**// your are printing min should be greater than max and you are checking the same.

Comment: "restrict it by simple console print"?  What does that even mean?

Comment: you can just show the throwing error msg on out stream  instead of creating exception object using same string and display it on out stream .

I don't think here is need for that much work.

Comment: What "stream"?  This object has no notion of a UI.  The consuming application can certainly direct the user to provide proper input, but that's not the responsibility of this object.  For all this object knows, there *is no* user.  A Windows Service, for example, wouldn't have a UI to display anything to a user.

Comment: Who said there was an output stream? (And even if there was, it should be the error stream, not the output stream). There's nothing saying this is a console application. If it's a library then maybe they don't even know if it'll be in a console or not.

Comment: yes you'r right . I m just try to say that where you can restrict the same thing without creating exception than why should use exception.
It's good to have exception handling in product but there are some higher level context. Just think for that it's simple one class program and it's handle user input than why should to throw exception. please feel free change my understanding regarding these. It will be very appreciable too.

Comment: @sulemanravla: The code in the question clearly isn't a "one class program".  It's just a class by itself, with no conception of an application host or user interface.  Any given application, with its own presentation layer, can certainly handle the responsibility of driving user input and handling errors appropriately with that user.  But the portable business objects do not have that responsibility.

Comment: @David yes ur absolutely right . I just mistakenly consider the scenario of not more than 2-3 classes here as per the exception throwing condition.

Comment: @sulemanravla: Even if there are only two classes, such as a `Program` class for a console application and this one business model, it's *still* not the responsibility of this class to maintain user input/output.  Object oriented principles apply to *every* object, not just ones in programs of significant enough size and complexity.  This class has a responsibility, it should maintain exactly that responsibility and *only* that responsibility.

Comment: @David thanks for sharing your views on may comments. It's really appreciable. thanks :)  We should not consider the size of product where as we should consider  design concepts and principles.